# Trying to access DB inside class Error

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, fetch

***Error : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null (...) fetch_my_db->fetch() #1 {main} thrown.***

I'm trying to access my db connection inside class but i get this error, if I copy & paste my try and catch connection inside of the class fetch_my_db it works. I need some help.

File Index.php Code ;

```
<?php

try {
    $ligação = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password');
    $ligação->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $erro) {
    echo $erro->getMessage();
    die();
}

class fetch_my_db {
    public function fetch() {
        $var = 'product';
        $sth = $ligação->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE type LIKE :parameter LIMIT 10');
        $sth->bindParam(':parameter', $var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->execute();
        $i = 1;
        while ($r = $sth->fetch()) {
            echo $r["title"] . " <br>";
            echo $r["type"] . " <br>";
            echo $r["price"] . " <br>";
        }
    }
}

$gotosql = new fetch_my_db();
$gotosql->fetch();

?>
```

Comment: Read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$ligação` does not exist within your class.

Comment: When i do this `$sth = $GLOBALS[ligação]->prepare` it works , but there is another more clean way ?

Comment: I'd suggest creating an overall database class, add the PDO creation to the `__construct()` function, then you can use that in any other class functions. There are plenty of tutorials out there that can explain the best way to create a database class.

Comment: I had do it before. I ll look it to it . Thank you.